# Strong tag Not working Android Webview

Tags: java, android, html

see below html code.i was loading this html page in browser working fine and supporting **STRONG** tag.

But Loading webview in android STRONG not working, it's look without bold.

I was tried many ways but not getting solution..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
     <html>
         <head>
         <title>rasikalinnavakriathanmai</title>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
         <style type="text/css">@font-face {font-family: MyCustomFont; src: url(Bamini.ttf)}body {font-family: MyCustomFont, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: medium; color: black}
         <!--
         body> p{font-size:20px;}
         .style1 {padding:10px;}
         .style3 {

            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
         }
         .style4 {font-size:20px;}
         -->
.style5{font-weight:bold}
         </style></head>
         <body>
         <table class = "style4"  width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
           <!--<tr> 
             <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#990000"><div align="center"><font ><strong><font color="#FFFFFF">uhrpfspy; 
                 etf;fpuf jd;ikfs;</font></strong></font></div></td>
           </tr>-->
           <tr> 
             <td width="30%"><div align="center"><font color="#000000"><strong>Nk\k;</strong></font></div></td>
             <td width="44%"><div align="center"><font color="#000000"><strong  class="style5">rpk;kk;</strong></font></div></td>
             <td width="26%"><div align="center"><font color="#000000"><strong>jDR</strong></font></div></td>
           </tr>
           <tr > 
             <td>R+upad; - cr;rk;<br>
               re;jpud; - rkk;<br>
               nrt;tha; - Ml;rp<br>
               Gjd; - rkk;<br>
               FU - el;G<br>
               Rf;fpud; - rkk;<br>
               rdp - ePrk;<br>
               uhF> NfJ - gif</td>
             <td>R+upad; - Ml;rp<br>
               re;jpud; - el;G<br>
               nrt;tha; - el;G<br>
               Gjd; - el;G<br>
              FU - el;G<br>
              Rf;fpud; - gif<br>
               rdp - gif<br>
               uhF> NfJ - gif</td>
             <td width="26%">R+upad; - el;G<br>
               re;jpud; - rkk;<br>
               nrt;tha; - el;G<br>
               Gjd; - rkk;<br>
               FU - Ml;rp<br>
               Rf;fpud; - el;G<br>
               rdp - rkk;<br>
               uhF> NfJ - el;G</td>
           </tr>
           <tr> 
             <td><div align="center"><strong>up\gk;</strong></div></td>
             <td><div align="center"><font color="#000000"><strong>fd;dp</strong></font></div></td>
             <td><div align="center"><font color="#000000" ><strong>kfuk;</strong></font></div></td>
           </tr>
           <tr> 
             <td>R+upad; - gif<br>
               re;jpud; - cr;rk;<br>
               nrt;tha; - rkk;<br>
               Gjd; - el;G<br>
               FU - gif<br>
               Rf;fpud; - Ml;rp<br>
               rdp - el;G<br>
               uhF> NfJ - ePrk;</td>
             <td>R+upad; - rkk;<br>
               re;jpud; - el;G<br>
               nrt;tha; - gif<br>
               Gjd; - Ml;rp> cr;rk;<br>
               FU - gif<br>
               Rf;fpud; - ePrk;<br>
               rdp - el;G<br>
               uhF> NfJ - el;G</td>
             <td>R+upad; - gif<br>
               re;jpud; - rkk;<br>
               nrt;tha; - cr;rk;<br>
               Gjd; - rkk;<br>
               FU - ePrk;<br>
               Rf;fpud; - el;G<br>
               rdp - Ml;rp<br>
               uhF> NfJ - el;G</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
   <td><div align="center"><font color="#000000" ><strong>kpJdk;</strong></font></div></td>
   <td><div align="center"><font color="#000000"><strong>Jyhk;</strong></font></div></td>
   <td><div align="center"><font color="#000000"><strong>Fk;gk;</strong></font></div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
   <td>R+upad; - rkk;<br>
     re;jpud; - el;G<br>
     nrt;tha; - gif<br>
     Gjd; - Ml;rp<br>
     FU - gif<br>
     Rf;fpud; - el;G<br>
     rdp - el;G<br>
     uhF> NfJ - el;G</td>
   <td>R+upad; - ePrk;<br>
     re;jpud; - rkk;<br>
     nrt;tha; - rkk;<br>
     Gjd; - el;G<br>
     FU - gif<br>
     Rf;fpud; - Ml;rp<br>
     rdp - cr;rk;<br>
     uhF> NfJ - el;G</td>
   <td>R+upad; - gif<br>
     re;jpud; - rkk;<br>
     nrt;tha; - rkk;<br>
              Gjd; - rkk;<br>
              FU - rkk;<br>
              Rf;fpud; - el;G<br>
              rdp - Ml;rp<br>
              uhF> NfJ - el;G</td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td><div align="center"><font color="#000000" ><strong>flfk;</strong></font></div></td>
            <td><div align="center"><font color="#000000"><strong>tpUr;rpfk;</strong></font></div></td>
            <td><div align="center"><font ><strong>kPdk;</strong></font></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td>R+upad; - rkk;<br>
              re;jpud; - Ml;rp<br>
              nrt;tha; - ePrk;<br>
              Gjd; - gif<br>
              FU - cr;rk;<br>
              Rf;fpud; - gif<br>
              rdp - gif<br>
              uhF> NfJ - gif</td>
            <td>R+upad; - el;G<br>
              re;jpud; - ePrk;<br>
              nrt;tha; - Ml;rp<br>
              Gjd; - rkk;<br>
              FU - el;G<br>
              Rf;fpud; - rkk;<br>
           rdp - gif<br>
           uhF> NfJ - cr;rk;</td>
         <td>R+upad; - el;G<br>
           re;jpud; - rkk;<br>
           nrt;tha; - el;G<br>
           Gjd; - ePrk;<br>
           FU - Ml;rp<br>
           Rf;fpud; - cr;rk;<br>
           rdp - rkk;<br>
           uhF> NfJ - el;G</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<strong>bold</strong>` please use the following-

```
<span class="sp_bold>bold</span>
```

and in your css-

```
span.sp_bold { font-weight: bold;}
```

You need to use `font-weight: bold;` not bolder as [webkit only supports](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56400) `bold`.

Answer (score 0):

Not all html tags are supported. Why won't you use `<b>` instead?

Comment: What do you mean <b> not supported? Did you try replacing the <strong> tags with <b>?

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to set font-family !!

```
{ font-family: "Interstate Light"; font-weight: normal; }
{ font-family: "Interstate Medium"; font-weight: normal; }
{ font-family: "Interstate Regular"; font-weight: normal; }
{ font-family: "Interstate Semibold"; font-weight: bold; }
{ font-family: "Interstate Bold"; font-weight: bold; }
{ font-family: "Interstate Extrabold"; font-weight: bold; }
{ font-family: "Interstate Black"; font-weight: bold; }
```